# PHP No response Issue

Tags: php, no-response

I have this piece of code I'm trying to get to display but no matter how I do it I just don't get any response or error whatsoever.

```
<?php
$day = array("Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado","Domingo");
//$month[]= array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

function today(){
    $d = date("N");
    switch ($d){
        case 1: 
            echo $day[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            echo $day[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            echo $day[3];
            break;
        case 4:
            echo $day[4];
            break;
        case 5:
            echo $day[5];
            break;
        case 6:
            echo $day[6];
            break;
        case 7:
            echo $day[7];
            break;
    }
} 
today();
?>
```

Can anyone see any obvious mistake I might be making and haven't noticed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid using global variables (which is [often-times a bad idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable)). You can just pass the variable in to the function.

Thus change the function declaration to

```
function today($day)
```

and the last function call to

```
today($day);
```

Note that the two $day's are not the same.

The `function today($day)` is simply saying that every $day variable within this function will contain the value that is passed in as this argument. It is **not** the array you declared. Therefore you can change this to whatever valid php variable name you want, along with all of the $days within the function scope and the result will remain the same.

The `today($day)` is saying pass in the `Array` $day that you declared before into the function `today`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add

```
global $day;
```

At the top of your function.

Check out the PHP manual on [`variable scoping`](https://www.php.net/global) for more. In addition to that, as [The.Anti.9 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523113/php-no-response-issue/523118#523118), you could just do:

```
$days = array("Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado","Domingo");
function today() {
    global $days;
    echo $days[date("N")-1];
}
today();
```

Comment: Oh yes that is a good point, I didn't even notice it was out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Well i don't see a mistake, but you could just do

```
echo $day[date('N')-1];
```

you need to remember that array indexes start at 0 not 1. So $day[7] will give you index error because theres is no 7.

EDIT:

as [paoloa bergantino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16417/paolo-bergantino) pointed out. You need to make the $day variable global, or you could put it inside the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Since `date('N')` returns you the day of the week (1 - 7) you could create also an 1-based index array:

```
$day = array(1 => "Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves",
                  "Viernes","Sábado","Domingo");
echo $day[date('N')];
```